# grep in IF statement

Tags: bash

The following script portion read each line in `$next`. But when I try to grep particular pattern i.e. `"MO"` in `$next`, the error is shown on standard output as:

```
grep: 40922|OPR: No such file or directory  
grep: MO: No such file or directory  
grep: 12345|OPR: No such file or directory  
grep: MO: No such file or directory   
grep: 12345|12345|202|local|LMNO: No such file or directory  

cat /home/scripts/$E1.out | while read next  
do  
i=`echo $next | awk -F"|" '{print($1)}'`
j=`echo $next | awk -F"|" '{print($2)}'`
k=`echo $next | awk -F"|" '{print($3)}'`
l=`echo $next | awk -F"|" '{print($4)}'`
m=`echo $next | awk -F"|" '{print($5)}'`
n=`echo $next | awk -F"|" '{print($6)}'`
o=`echo $next | awk -F"|" '{print($6)}'`  
if grep -q "MO" $next  
then echo "FOUND;" >> /home/scripts/sql.$E1.out  
else echo "NOT FOUND;" >> /home/scripts/sql.$E1.out  
fi  
done
```

`$E1.out` files looks like :

```
40922|OPR MO 12345|OPR MO 12345|12345|202|local|LMNO
```

Comment: On a separate note, you can avoid all the invocations of awk by changing the read command slightly: `while IFS="|" read i j k l m n o; do ...` (note that this just sets IFS for the read command, so you don't have to set it back afterward).

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The argument you pass in to [`grep`](http://opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xcu/grep.html), `$next`, is being treated as a list of filenames to search through. If you would like to search within that line for a string, say, `MO`, then you need to either put it in a file and pass that file in as an argument, or pipe it in via standard input.

Here's an example that you can try out on the command line; of course, substitute the variable that you're using for the literal value that I included to illustrate:

```
if echo "40922|OPR MO 12345|OPR MO 12345|12345|202|local|LMNO" | grep -q "MO"
  then echo "FOUND"
  else echo "NOT FOUND"
fi
```

Comment: Can't we do like : if echo "$next" | grep -q "MO" ? I mean i have to search line by line and there can be many lines in $E1.out.

Comment: @Ashish Yes, you can do `if echo "$next"`. As I said, I put the literal value in there for purpose of illustration, but you can instead put the variable that you're using to hold the current line.

Answer (score 4):

```
if grep -q "MO" ${E1}.out then
  echo "found"
else
  echo "not found"
fi
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 if tmux ls | grep -q "ABC"; then echo "1";  else echo "2"; fi
```

Comment: Usually it's better to explain a solution instead of just posting some rows of anonymous code. You can read [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), and also [Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bcode-based-answers).