# How to grep and then fail an if-statement on specific output from grep?

Tags: bash, error-handling, if-statement, grep

Ok I need to find the output that a command gives, notely "gbak: ERROR" and then fail on it. I don't know if I'm going about it the right way, I tried to make if fail if the grep did an output to /dev/null but I couldn't get that working either (probably just poor syntax). I'm sure this is a simple one, please let me know.

The if statement I've got at the moment is:

```
if [ `sudo -u firebird $GBAK_COMMAND | grep "gbak: ERROR"` == *gbak: ERROR* ]; then
   echo "$DATE Unsucessful $1.gdb Gbak. Incorrect user/password" >> /var/log/messages
   echo "Failed"
   exit 1
else
   echo "pass"
fi
```

Comment: Instead of backticks, which are deprecated, you should always use $(...) if you need. It is better readable, font-agnostic and you can easyly nest it `a=$(b $(c $(d)) $(e))`

Comment: Related: [Grep output of command and use it in “if” statement, bash](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19838118/320399) and [grep in IF statement](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3943854/320399)

Comment: Also related: [How do I use a file grep comparison inside a bash if/else statement?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2480584/320399)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You don't need the 'test' operator square brackets; just test the exit status of `grep`:

```
if sudo -u firebird $GBAK_COMMAND | grep -q "gbak: ERROR"
then
   echo "$DATE Unsuccessful $1.gdb Gbak. Incorrect user/password" >> /var/log/messages
   echo "Failed"
   exit 1
else
   echo "pass"
fi
```

The `-q` option to `grep` suppresses all output (POSIX and GNU variants) so you just get the status, which the `if` tests.  If `grep` finds the pattern, it returns success, which means that the `firebird` command failed.  The only residual issue is 'does `firebird` write its error to standard output or to standard error?' If you need to redirect the standard error, write:

```
if sudo -u firebird $GBAK_COMMAND 2>&1 | grep -q "gbak: ERROR"
then
   echo "$DATE Unsuccessful $1.gdb Gbak. Incorrect user/password" >> /var/log/messages
   echo "Failed"
   exit 1
else
   echo "pass"
fi
```

Comment: For GNU grep, you might want `-q` instead of/in addition to `-s` (GNU `-s` only suppresses complaints about unreadable files and such, not matched lines).

Comment: Great work, thanks! I've fixed it up now no problems. Yes very interesting, if I don't have 2>&1 there it will pass straight over it as if it's passed. I need to learn about this std error stuff as I don't know too much about it or what it does.

Comment: @Jeremiah: yes - you're right; and it is not just GNU `grep` but also POSIX.  I'll modify the answer - thanks.