# Grep output of command and use it in "if" statement, bash

Tags: bash, if-statement, grep, command, output

Okay so here's another one about the StarMade server.

Previously I had this script for detecting a crash, it would simply search through the logs:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd "$(dirname "$0")"
if ( grep "[SERVER] SERVER SHUTDOWN" log.txt.0); then
sleep 7; kill -9 $(ps -aef | grep -v grep | grep 'StarMade.jar' | awk '{print $2}')
fi
```

It would find "[SERVER] SERVER SHUTDOWN" and kill the process after that, however this is not a waterproof method, because with different errors it could be possible that the message doesn't appear, rendering this script useless.

So I have this tool that can send commands to the server, but returns an EOF exception when the server is in a crashed state. I basically want to grab the output of this command, and use it in the if-statement above, instead of the current grep command, in such a way that it would execute the commands below when the grep finds "java.io.EOFException".

I could make it write the output to a file and then grep it from there, but I wonder, isn't there a better/more efficient method to do this?

EDIT: okay, so after a bit of searching I put together the following:

```
if ( java -jar /home/starmade/StarMade/StarNet.jar xxxxx xxxxx /chat) 2>&1 > /dev/null |grep java.io.EOFException);
```

Would this be a valid if-statement? I need it to match "java.io.EOFException" in the output of the first command, and if it matches, to execute something with "then" (got that part working).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure to solve your problem, but this line:

```
ps -aef | grep -v grep | grep 'StarMade.jar' | awk '{print $2}'
```

could be change to

```
ps -aef | awk '/[S]tarMade.jar/ {print $2}'
```

The `[S]` prevents `awk` from finding itself.

---

Or just like this to get the `pid`

```
pidof StarMade.jar
```

Comment: Oh okay, not a solution for the problem but thanks for letting me know nevertheless :)