# VboxManage list vms Linux Shell Script Always Outputs wrong result

Tags: linux, bash, shell, virtualbox

What am I doing wrong. I'm sure what I'm attempting to do should be clear to everyone.

```
#/usr/bin/env sh
echo -e "What VM?"
read vname
if [ '`VboxManage list vms | grep -c "$vname"`' != 0 ]; then
    echo exists
fi
```

Anyone have suggestions. Pretty much it should tell me if the VM exist or not.

Comment: The single-quotes prevent expansion of the whole `VboxManage ...` command -- it's just treated as a static string. But there's a much simpler way to test whether `grep` found any matches; see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5227428/bash-script-if-statement-how-to-grep-for-then-fail-on-specified-output).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First your shebang is wrong.

Try this code

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
echo -e "What VM?"
read -r vname
if [ "$(VboxManage list vms | grep -c "$vname")" != 0 ]; then
    echo exists
fi
```

Comment: Also I noticed after I wrote the code that on Linux based systems it wouldn't work because of case sensitive syntax. VBoxManage