# How to use grep in if statement in shell

Tags: bash, shell, zsh

I have this shall script, basically I need to print all `<sst>` result only when `<pr>` is found.

Probably I have some syntax error so when I run the script I receive a message "Display all possibilities" basically the `grep` does not work.

Could you please help me out to understand what is the problem here?

```
declare -a arr=(
"123"
"345"
)

for i in "${arr[@]}"
do
   echo "$i"
    if [grep -q "<pr>$i</pr>" ./archiv]
    then
        grep -r "<sst>" ./archiv
    fi
done
```

Comment: You need a space after `[` and before `]` in your `if` statement

Comment: `bash` or `zsh`? They are two different shells.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [grep in IF statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3943854/grep-in-if-statement)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is very likely no command named `[grep`.  Drop the `[`

```
if grep -q "<pr>$i</pr>" ./archiv; then ...
```

`[` is not and has never been a part of the shell grammar.  It is a command, just like `echo` or `test` or `grep`.  The value returned by that command is used to determine whether or not to execute the clause of the `if` statement.